# Querying between precise times

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, shell

I'm trying to create a bash script that will query a SQL database exactly between 12AM to 11:59PM for the previous day.

Currently I have:

```
QUERY="SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER.CREATE_DATE >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY ) INTO OUTFILE '/stuff/a.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';"
```

So essentially I want to replace CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY with what I described above.

I can't hard code it because the day consistently changes and I'm not familiar enough with bash/SQL syntax to knowhow to change the above query for this.

It's also possible that CURDATE() solves this, but I'd like someone to verify this.

Edit: It's MySQL.

Comment: you need to tell us what RDBMS (MySQL, ORACLE, sqlite) it is, ad date functions are slightly different for different vendors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QUERY="SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMER.CREATE_DATE >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY ) and TIME(CUSTOMER.CREATE_DATE) >= '12:00' and TIME(CUSTOMER.CREATE_DATE) <= '23:59' INTO OUTFILE '/stuff/a.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';"
```